# Are these real badges for Richard Nixon's 1972 Presidential campaign?

Tags: politics

I saw this image [on Twitter earlier](https://twitter.com/RichStanton/status/618439544015331328), claiming that they're actual campaign badges for Richard Nixon's 1972 election:

[image]

I believe this is a notable claim, as some other websites report on them (though this link at least claims that it was an *unofficial* slogan):

http://willrabbe.com/microblog/2011/6/1/most-underrated-political-slogan-they-cant-lick-our-dick.html

> One of the more humorous, unofficial, historic campaign slogans was "They Can't Lick Our Dick," which was used on at least four different campaign buttons for Richard Nixon.

Is there any evidence that pins sporting the slogan "They Can't Lick our Dick" were in use for the 1972 presidential election, or have they been produced after the fact?

Comment: In theory, it was also on [a poster](http://www.amazon.com/Richard-Nixon-1972-Vintage-Poster/dp/B004ILT422).

Comment: [This auction site credits the button with being genuine](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/8972477_political-button-lot-they-cant-lick-our-dick).

Comment: @DJClayworth The button on the auction site shows a much younger Nixon compare to the similar one in the OP.

Comment: Is that button implying that there was someone running against Nixon named Mr. McGovern? Because that is a ridiculous name for a government official.

Comment: The 3 1/2" anti-George McGovern button is authentic "McGOVERN CAN'T LICK OUR DICK" I bought several at the APIC Convention in 1972 in San Diego.

Comment: @JonathonWisnoski See: [Wiki: George McGovern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_McGovern)

Comment: Recently, a Facebook page _Historic Photographs_ has brought this photo of badges: [Campaign slogans for Nixon (1972). Dick - Richard.](https://www.facebook.com/HistoricPhotographs/posts/1091029214404161)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Association of Nixon with the phrase "They Can't Lick our Dick" started well before 1972.

In the 1960 [The Realist](https://books.google.com/books?id=U5jWAAAAMAAJ&q=nixon%20campaign%20slogan%20%22can't%20lick%20our%22&dq=nixon%20campaign%20slogan%20%22can't%20lick%20our%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=og2dVY_kIYWrgwT0pYP4CQ&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAg):

> a sponsor tries to sign up Nixon and Kennedy for a TV special next April because they've been getting such good rating and a novelty shop sells buttons that read "They Can't Lick Our Dick"

The 1988 [Tippecanoe and Trinkets Too: The Material Culture of American Presidential Campaigns, 1828-1984](https://books.google.com/books?id=q8DWAAAAMAAJ&q=nixon%20campaign%20slogan%20%22can't%20lick%20our%22&dq=nixon%20campaign%20slogan%20%22can't%20lick%20our%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=og2dVY_kIYWrgwT0pYP4CQ&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAQ) refers to:

> Another humanizing tactic was the great prominence given Nixon's nickname, "Dick," on campaign items, although some uniquely tasteless varieties of buttons that read "They Can't Lick Our Dick"— at least one of them given out by the campaign itself

Again, this is said in reference to the 1960 Nixon vs. Kennedy election.

Comment: and seems to indicate that no, they were not official campaign material but rather created by an independent individual as a souvenir.

Comment: @jwenting "at least one of them given out by the campaign itself"